# Creating a GnuPG keyring for apache

Tags: rhel, encryption, gpg, gpg-agent

Here's the scenario, we're using GnuPG to encrypt data between 2 web servers. 1 is on RHEL. GnuPG will be accessed through cgi scripts to encrypt and decrypt. So I need a keyring that the apache user has access to. This has proven to be difficult for me on Red Hat, I was able to get this set up pretty easily on Ubuntu. Here's what I've tried to, maybe someone has a better/easier way to accomplish this.

I became the apache user

```
su -s /bin/bash apache
```

when running

```
gpg --gen-key
```

it couldn't create the .gnupg directory at /var/www, so I created that and set the owner to apache.apache. now when generating keys, I get

```
can't connect to `/var/www/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent': No such file or directory
gpg-agent[26949]: command get_passphrase failed: Operation cancelled
gpg: cancelled by user
gpg: Key generation canceled.
```

so I created that file, after reading the man page a bit (and some googling)

```
mknod -m 700 S.gpg-agent p
```

now I get

```
can't connect to `/var/www/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent': Connection refused
gpg-agent[26949]: command get_passphrase failed: Operation cancelled
gpg: cancelled by user
gpg: Key generation canceled.
```

I haven't been able to get anywhere after this as I'm getting into areas I don't know much about. I'm assuming it has to do with that apache isn't really a user in the since of having a bash profile, etc. So where do I go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried creating a new user and invoking the command with sudo instead? If fear this might be some permission issue and the easier way would be removing the agent node from /var/www to somewhere we know is accessible to the gpg user, maybe the /tmp directory. You can manually specify the agent node location changing the env variable GPG_AGENT_INFO.

Comment: Are you saying to run "sudo" inside the CGI script itself?

Comment: yes, as soon you don't have any parameters is should be relatively safe. For added security you can always specify allowed commands in  /etc/sudoers

Comment: I was able to import keys into the keyring, however, when trying to sign them, I'm back to where I started:

`can't connect to `/var/www/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent: No such file or directory`
`gpg-agent[24458]: command get_passphrase failed: Operation cancelled`
`gpg: cancelled by user`
`gpg: signing failed: General error`
`Key not changed so no update needed.`

Answer (score 2):

That is probably a device file permission problem. `pinentry` doesn't use the inherited file descriptors but tries to access the passed TTY directly which doesn't work.

You may run `tty` in the shell and afterwards `ls -l /dev/pts/1` with the result and you will probably notice that `apache` does not have access to it.

You may also run

```
strace -o gpg.strace -f -e trace=open gpg --gen-key
```

and will probably find something like

```
open("/dev/pts/1", O_RDONLY)      = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

The dangerous solution is to (temporarily) give `apache` access to a `root` console... (`chown apache /dev/pts/1`). The better solution is to make a real login as `apache`.

This affects key generation only. You could also create a key pair as another user, export it and import in in the `apache` account.

Comment: We actually discussed doing this yesterday. I'll give this a try and see how it goes. Thanks

Comment: Another option rather than modifying the device permissions is: export GPG_TTY=/dev/tty

Comment: +1 I've faced this problem also in SLES 11 SP4. Setting `GPG_TTY` as suggested by @RussellReed did not help. I neither like chmod'ing (or chown'ing) `$tty`, so I instead ssh into the account from which I need to sign artifacts (In my case, I already had keys but needed to sign some objects). As support links, see also https://bugs.gnupg.org/gnupg/issue1391 and https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2009-May/036544.html

Comment: Alberto, just to double check, you specified /dev/tty and didn't try to substitute the actual tty device, like /dev/pts/1, right?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's a regression regarding this bug https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2011-1096.html

From the errata:

> This update fixes the following bug:
>
> - Prior to this update, there was a problem when entering a password using the
>     pinentry-curses utility; an error message was displayed instead of the password
>     entry dialog if pinentry-curses was run under a user different from the user who
>     owned the current tty. This bug has been fixed in this update so that no error
>     message is now displayed and pinentry-curses asks for a password as expected.
>     (BZ#677665)

The problem appears to be, when you su or sudo, the tty is still owned by the original owner of the tty, which blows up pinentry.

I will note that we couldn't create gpg keys as any user other than root on a Cent 6 system yesterday.  To generate the keys, we had to log in as root, create the keys, copy the .gpg dir to the user's home directory and change the ownership.